# Grunt workflow with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, gruntjs

I am using Grunt with Sublime Text 2. I have set up all my tasks, including watch. Everything works fine when, upon sparking up Sublime, I command grunt to begin watching, then make changes to files.

But say I forget to begin watching, and I start making edits, those changes are not compiled until making a future change to the file while under watch. (My default task is watch.)

I know I can run tasks individually to update my files, but I'm wondering if there is a better workflow for this. Perhaps auto start watch right when starting up my editor?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using sublime with the [sublime-grunt](https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt) package.

Via `Cmd-Alt-P` -> `Grunt` I choose `watch` and then watch starts in the bottom window of Sublime. That way I see `grunt watch` generating the files after I save and I know that something is running and/or there are errors

Comment: Thanks. Yes -- I know once watch runs that all changes are saved. I was referring to changes made BEFORE watch is begun. A way to auto-start watch when opening a project, perhaps.

Comment: for me created a task called `dev` which builds so once watch is started everything is built: `grunt.registerTask('dev', ['uglify:dev', 'assemble', 'connect', 'watch']);`

Comment: Perfect! Should have jumped out at me. Thanks.